# Hardware accelerated Live Wallpaper

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Live Wallpaper that can leverage HArdware acceleration on sdk 14.
But Live wallpaper I create is using:

```
Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
```

And Romain Guy already mentioned Canvas created by such methods are not hardware accelerated.
So is there an alternative way by which I can create a Canvas for LWP?

p.s. I'm not using any of the unsupported hardware-accelerated canvas methods.